# Show that the Moebius band deformation retracts to a homeomorphic copy of $S^1$.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, mobius-band

I can show that the unit square deformation retracts to a line and that line under a particular equivalence relation is homeomorphic to $S^1$.

Let $X = [0,1] \times [0,1]$ and define an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $X$ by $(0,s) \sim (1,1-s)$. Then the Moebius band is defined to be $M := X/\sim$ and we have the canonical quotient map $q: X \to M$ defined by $q(x, y) = [(x, y)]_{\sim}$.

For each $t \in [0,1]$, define the map $r_t: X \to [0,1] \times [0, 1-t]$ by $r_t(x, y) = \left(x, \, y(1-t)\right)$. Then it is clear that $r_t$ is a retraction and we get a deformation retraction of $X$ onto $A := [0,1] \times \{0\}$, $F: X \times [0,1] \to X$ defined by $F(x, t) = r_t(x)$.

I know in general that quotient maps don't preserve deformation retractions ([quotient map preserves deformation retraction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3471886/quotient-map-preserves-deformation-retraction)) but I want to say it does in this case. I attempt to define a deformation retraction from $M$ onto $q(A)$, $G: M \times [0,1] \to M$ by $G(x, t) = (q \circ r_t) (x)$. To show it satisfies the properties of a deformation retraction, I need to show

1. For every $[(x,y)] \in M$, $G([x,y], 0) = [x, y]$.
2. For every $[(x,y)] \in M$, $G([x,y], 1) \in q(A)$.
3. For every $[(a, b)] \in q(A)$, $G([a, b], 1) = [a, b]$.

This issue is that why should $G$ be well-defined?

Comment: Your post has a rather terrible clash of variables: $t$ is used as a parameter in defining the equivalence relation $(0,t) \sim (1,1-t)$; and $t$ is also used as a paremeter in $r_t$ and $G(x,t)$. Since well-definedness of $G(x,t)$ can only be verified using the equivalence relation, I advise cleaning up this issue first.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out @LeeMosher. I've fixed it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proposed retraction does not descend to the quotient, hence $G$, as it's written is *not* well-defined. The problem is that it collapses the square to the "bottom" where $y=0$, but in the Möbius band, there is no well-defined "bottom" edge. To wit, at the boundary: $r_t(0, y) = (0, y(1-t))$ and $r_t(1, y) = (1, y(1-t))$, but these points have to agree in the quotient! At $t=1$,
$$
r_1(0, y) = (0, 0)
$$
and
$$
r_1(1, y) = (1, 0)
$$
but $(0, 0) \not\sim (1, 0)$.

You can salvage this idea, but you need to shrink the square $[0, 1] \times [0, 1]$ towards the "equator" $[0, 1] \times \bigl\{ \tfrac12 \bigr\}$, since
$$
\bigl( 0, \tfrac12 \bigr) \sim \bigl( 1, \tfrac12 \bigr). 
$$

Can you figure out the appropriate function $r_t$?

Comment: Is it $r_t:[0,1] \times [0,1] \to [0,1] \times \left[\frac{1}{2}t, \, 1 - \frac{1}{2}t \right]$ where $r_{t}\left(x,y\right)=\left(x,\ y+t\left(\frac{1}{2}-y\right)\right)$?

Comment: Yes, that looks good. Note that you can write the $y$-coordinate as $(1-t)y + t \cdot \tfrac12$ to make it clear that the value varies linearly from $y$ at $t=0$ to $\tfrac12$ at $t=1$.